# Trying to find a way to use same key for different value

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm new to programming and I'm writing a small program in Python to abbreviate words in a sentence using "dictionary". The idea is that I would write out a sentence and any word that is included as a key would return its abbreviated value.
I'm using the `split()` method to help accomplish this. The issue is when I have a key that partially resembles another, for instance the key "account" would be printed as "acct" but when I want a different key "account takeover" to be printed as "ato" it will not work. I'm assuming the split() is now working against me. I looked through string methods and dictionary methods but couldn't come up with a solution. Any ideas? Greatly appreciate any help.

```
notes = input("Notes: ")

def simple_library(notes):
    abbreviate = notes.lower().split(" ")
    abbreviate_sentence = {
        "account": "acct",
        "account takeover": "ato"
    }
    output = ""
    for words in abbreviate:
        output += abbreviate_sentence.get(words, words) + " "
    return output.upper()


print(simple_library(notes))
```

Notes: account, account takeover

ACCOUNT, ACCT TAKEOVER

I would like for it to print as 
ACCOUNT, ATO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work if you split the input into words.

Instead of using a dictionary, you can use a list that contains regular expressions that match the words and phrases you want to match, along with their abbreviations, and you call `re.sub()` for every one of them.

You should order this so that the longer matches are first. Otherwise, it will replace `account` before trying to replace `account takeover`.

You should use a regexp rather than an ordinary string so that you can match word boundaries with `\b`. Otherwise, it can abbreviate a word when it's part of another word, e.g. turn `accounting` into `accting`.

So the code would look like:

```
import re

def simple_library(notes):
    notes = notes.lower()
    abbreviate_sentence = [
        (r"\baccount\s+takeover\b", "ato"),
        (r"\baccount\b", "acct")
    ]
    for regexp, replace in abbreviate_sentence:
        notes = re.sub(regexp, replace, notes)
    return notes.upper()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give it a shot